# Problem Deploying Application On JBOSS with multiple data source

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, datasource, jndi

Hi I am trying to deploy two war files on JBOSS EAP 7.1.
Both of these are spring boot Applications for which i have configured JNDI Look up.
My Standalone.xml file looks like something like this..

```
 <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/JNDI1" pool-name="JNDIPool1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>test1</user-name>
                    <password>test1</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/JNDI2" pool-name="JNDIPool2" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema_2</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>test2</user-name>
                    <password>test2</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Each of thes war files uses different JNDI look up.When I deploy them at the same time One of the War gets deployed where as the other gets failed with the following error. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
     ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TEST.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "TEST.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./.session is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:235)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:768)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2555)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2555)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:317)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentProcessor.lambda$processDeployment$0(UndertowDeploymentProcessor.java:405)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(UndertowDeploymentProcessor.java:405)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentProcessor.deploy(UndertowDeploymentProcessor.java:190)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Did my provided solution resolve you query ? Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi @AmithKumar yes that did solve my issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help. Please accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Please allocate different context-root for each application in web.xml. I am guessing you are using default `<context-root>/</context-root>`, causing DuplicateServiceException for second war. Change it to `<context-root>/app1</context-root>` & `<context-root>/app2</context-root>`